# jquery val function get new value from textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea, jquery-click-event

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/opmaster/RALDF/6/) is a jsfiddle

here is my html

```
<table id="commentsTable">
        <tr>
            <td name="userid"> JIM </td>
            <td name="comment" id="68" class="commentTD">  something   </td>
            <td><a class="edit" href="#">edit</a></td>
        </tr>
</table>​
```

and my js:

```
var update = "update";

$("a.edit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var comment = $(this).closest("tr").find('.commentTD');
    comment.html('<textarea name="comment" class="commentArea">' + comment.text() + '</textarea>');
    $(this).removeClass().addClass(update).text(update);
    bindUpdate();
});

function bindUpdate() {
    $("a." + update).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var commentNewText = $(this).closest('tr').find('textarea.commentArea').val();
        alert(commentNewText);
    });
};​
```

I am able to add a textarea and bind a click event to it, but I can't seem to get the **new value**, I get the old one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not unbinding the old event from your link, so it still adds a new textarea each time you click it and only THEN it calls the bindUpdate() functionality.

See this updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RALDF/8/

**EDIT:** I would suggest to save value of `$(this)` into a variable and re-use it, since you're calling it multiple times, which has a negative impact on performance /jQuery needs to make new object every time you do $(this)/

Comment: that's weird. I saw that it worked, but I don't understand why. the old event was on class `edit` but I am changing that class so that event will no longer be valid.

Comment: events are not bound to classes but to elements themselves... you don't remove the old link element, only change its class and text, thus still leaving the first bound functionality intact

Comment: hi zathus, still weird, I remeber doing exactly this not too long ago (last week). thanks for the quick reply! + thanks for the other comment about the $(this) element also!

Answer (score 2):

You're getting your first handler triggered before the new one. If you add `unbind` to the first handler it work ok ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RALDF/7/)). To acheive this in a more predictable way you may extract your handlers to the separate functions.